# Kohana - Views Within Views

Tags: php, kohana

I have problem with passing variables through views. But, first some code

```
// i enter the url http://localhost/my_projects/blog/index/index
// classes/controller/index.php
class Controller_Index extends Controller
{
    protected $rendered_view;

    public function before()
    {
        $this->rendered_view = View::factory('index')
                ->set('head', View::factory('subpages/head')
                               ->set('title', 'Site title')
                     )
                ->set('nav', View::factory('subpages/nav')
                               ->set('title', 'Site title')
                     )
                ->set('header', View::factory('subpages/header')
                                ->set('h1', 'Header H1')
                     )
                ->set('sidebar', View::factory('subpages/sidebar')
                                ->set('h1', 'Header H1')
                     )
                ->set('content', View::factory('subpages/content')
                                ->set('h2', 'Header H2')
                                ->set('content', 'some content')
                     )
                ->set('footer', View::factory('subpages/footer')
                                ->set('footer', 'some footer')
                     );
    }

    public function action_index()
    {
        $this->response->body($this->rendered_view);
    }
}
```

And in view index i pass variables to the default view:

```
// views/index.php
echo View::factory('default')->set('head', $head);
echo View::factory('default')->set('nav', $nav);
echo View::factory('default')->set('header', $header);
echo View::factory('default')->set('sidebar', $sidebar);
echo View::factory('default')->set('content', $content);
echo View::factory('default')->set('footer', $footer);
```

And i try in display view i try "echo" variables:

```
// views/default.php
echo $head; 
echo $nav; 
echo $header; 
echo $sidebar; 
echo $content; 
echo $footer;
```

And it throw error:

```
ErrorException [ 2 ]: file_put_contents(/some_path/application/logs/2011/02/23.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied ~ SYSPATH/classes/kohana/log/file.php [ 81 ]
```

If i write something like that:

```
// views/default.php
include Kohana::find_file('views', 'default');
```

it display valid;

Comment: Just a note - your `before`'s code should be moved to `action_index()`, and `action_index()` to `after()`. And dont forget about `parent::before()`/`parent::after()` calls!

Comment: But I wanted to set default values for views and if it should be change in other methods then it will be changed and I don't have to set other values that will be the same for various methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

chmod 777 `/some_path/application/logs/2011/02/23.php` file and all directory `/some_path/application/logs/` recursively

**UPD:**

maybe

```
// views/index.php
echo View::factory('default')
->set('head', $head)
->set('nav', $nav)
->set('header', $header)
->set('sidebar', $sidebar)
->set('content', $content)
->set('footer', $footer);
```

Comment: Very strange now it cant see variable in default view: ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: nav | ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: head

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is Kohana is throwing an exception and trying to log the error, but can't save the log file.

Make sure /application/logs is writable (755, or 777 on some servers)

Comment: I already did it, but it throws some errors:  ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: nav | ErrorException [ Notice ]: Undefined variable: head